# Why does my highchart only expand horizontally to fill its containing div, and not vertically?

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jer2/W8xsY/1/)

I'm using highcharts-ng.  In the Fiddle above, I've created the most simple case that shows the problem I'm having - when the chart is enclosed in a div, it expands horizontally to fill it, but not vertically.

Why is this?  Is there a way I can make it expand vertically as well?

SO won't let me post this without code, so here's what's in the above fiddle:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <div id="chartContainer" >
        <highchart id="chart1" config="chartConfig"></highchart>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#chartContainer {
background-color: #AF3456;
width:777px;
height:500px;
padding:10px;
```

}

JavaScript:

```
    //See: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

    $scope.chartConfig = {
        series: [{
            data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
        }],
    }



});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't specify a [chart height](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart.height) in your config, highcharts will:

> By default the height is calculated from the offset height of the
>   containing element, or **400 pixels if the containing element's height
>   is 0**.

In your case your your "containing element" is `<highchart id="chart1"...` (not `<div id="chartContainer" >`) and since it's 0 height highchart uses 400 pixels.

See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W8xsY/3/).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe better is using a correct CSS styles.

```
body, html {border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; 
height:100%; position:relative; width:100%;}

#chart-wrapper,#chart-wrapper div {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
#chartContainer {
    background-color: #AF3456;
    width:97%!important;
    height:97%!important;
    padding:1%;
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/W8xsY/7/